# How to hide "Filter user list" from "All Users" screen

Tags: users

Is there a way to remove the "Filter user list" from the top of the "All Users" screen for non-admins?

For clarification its the section which lists totals for each user role type and filters the table when clicked eg:

```
All (5) | Administrator (1) | Editor (3) | Subscriber (1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `views_users` filter to alter it. Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Remove the users view
 */
add_filter( 'views_users', '__return_empty_array' );
```

if you want to remove it for every user.

Here's another example how you could remove it for non-admins (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
/**
 * Remove the users view for non-admins
 */
add_filter( 'views_users', function( $views ) 
{
    return current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ? $views : [];
} );
```